# Find out who added a column to my SharePoint 2013 library

Tags: 2013, document-library, column, auditing

We're trying to find out who added a specific column to our library.

I can see some info about the fields via the REST API, but not exactly what I wanted at the level of who created the column:

```
http://mysite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Event%20Log')/fields
```

I'm not finding any way to do this since auditing is not enabled.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible. If you open up SharePoint Manager, Created By is not a property in the field's Schema XML both for out of the box fields and custom fields.

Comment: Thanks SkinnyE...correct, we couldn't find anything in SharePoint Designer either to help find out the answer to who may have added this column.